# How to Maximize[Log[n]^(1/Log[n]), n]

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am new to Mathematica and am trying to work out how to use Maximize.

```
Maximize[Log[n]^(1/Log[n]),n]
```

Should give a solution at $e^e$.  However in Mathematica you don't get anything. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Maximize[{Log[n]^(1/Log[n]), n > 1}, n]

(* {E^(1/E), {n -> E^E}} *)
```

Comment: `Log[1]` is ... mmmm ...

Comment: Oh, you think it gives up without `n>1` because it doesn't know what to do with complex expressions?

Comment: $e^{\mathrm{mmmm}}-1=0$: belisarius' identity.

Comment: Thank you.  `Limit[Log[x]^(1/Log[x]), x->1]`  is $0$ .

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Solve` to find where the derivative is 0:

```
Solve[D[Log[n]^(1/Log[n]), n] == 0, n]
(* {{n -> E^E}} *)
```

I find it strange that `Maximize` doesn't realize this.

Comment: Thank you.  That was how I did it in the end. I was just trying to work out how to use Maximize for when I can't find the solution so easily.